# Assigning an instance's method from another class?

Tags: c#, methods

I have a finalised class called `SimObject`. In this class, there is a public function called `Draw()`.

Instead of extending and overriding from `SimObject` in another new class, I would like to assign a method to replace `Draw()` from my Main class. The Main class creates the `SimObject` and holds an instance of it. So how can I do something like this:

```
public class Main {
   public static void Main() {
      //constructor 
      var obj = new SimObject();
      obj.Draw = MyNewDrawMethod;
   }

   public void MyNewDrawMethod() {
      //some code
   }
}
```

Is this possible in c#?

Comment: Is it sealed by you or is it from an assembly which you can't change?

Comment: You've changed `sealed` to `finalized` in your question. What do you mean exactly? Is it `sealed`? Can it be inherited from? If it isn't `sealed`, then you can simply override the `Draw` method in a derived class..

Comment: It is from an assembly. I have no access to the code. It is sealed and finalised. So I can't really extend it.

Comment: There's no such thing as "finalized" in C#, btw. I guess you just mean "sealed".

Comment: @MatthewWatson "Technically" there is.. but not in this context..

Comment: There's a Finalizer, so I suppose once that's been run the object could be considered "Finalized". But that's a temporal issue. In any case, a class cannot be "Finalized" - only an instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) if you do not want to inherit it but want to extend it.

```
public class MyList{


}

public static class MyZListExtesion
{
    public static void DrawSomethingElse(this MyList obj)
    {
        // override Draw from here
    }
}
```

**and the usage**

new MyList().DrawSomethingElse();

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't allow you to assign the method but you can add functionality using an extension method.

```
public static class SimObjectExtensions
{
    public static void Draw(this SimObject obj)
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

This will allow you to use the Draw method as if it were an instance method of SimObject

```
SimObject o = new SimObject();
o.Draw();
```

Comment: If the extension method has the same name and parameters as an existing method, the existing method will be called - so this won't help.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't notice the object already had a `Draw` method. If he actually needs to `override`, because Draw is part of some template method or whatever it sounds like he's stuffed. Might it be possible to do something funky with reflection?